# NSWorkspace notification not received

Tags: swift, macos

My function isn't being executed when I switch apps:

```
public class ItemObserver: NSObject {

  @objc public func recievedNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    print(notification.name)
    print("s")
  }
}

let observer = ItemObserver()

NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(observer, selector: #selector(ItemObserver.recievedNotification(notification:)), name: .NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplication, object: nil)
```

Comment: Is the `NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver` line executed?

Comment: Yes. It's a console application, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Instead of `ItemObserver()`, try keeping an instance of the object in your class.

Comment: Are you talking about a shared instance? That didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that NSNotifications don't run concurrently. I had a while loop further down.

Comment: This is why we say "show the code"!  The (second) code you posted was perfectly fine.  The bug was in the part you omitted.

Answer (score 0):

NSNotificationCenter doesn't retain the observer: it uses a [zeroing weak reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter), where possible.  If you log its `init` and `deinit`, you'll see that it's being released right away.

Keep a strong reference to the observer.

Comment: I added an observer variable and it still didn't execute the function.

Comment: @NemoIngen Then please edit your question and show your code that does what you claim.

Comment: I pasted your (updated) code in a blank file, with `import AppKit` above it and  `RunLoop.current.run()` below it, and it correctly prints a notification whenever I switch apps.